# Swipe between tabbar pages in Xamarin Shell

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer, xamarin.forms.shell

I use bottom menu and disable flyout.
For IOS I needed to add swipe gesture to shell. I used custom render.

How to add swipe animation?
On Android for tabbed page it works out of box.
I need something similar for Xamarin Shell tabbar menu.
I thought Xamarin Forms is pretty easy to use without any problems. It’s basic thing it should be implemented

````
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShell), typeof(CustomShellRenderer))]
namespace ShellDemo.iOS
{
    public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        protected override IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker()
        {
            return new CustomTabbarAppearance();
        }
    }

    public class CustomTabbarAppearance : IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public void ResetAppearance(UITabBarController controller)
        {

        }

        public void SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipeRight = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer((gesture) =>
            {
                if (controller.SelectedIndex > 0)
                {
                    controller.SelectedIndex--;
                }
            });
            swipeRight.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right;
            controller.View.AddGestureRecognizer(swipeRight);

            UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipeLeft = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer((gesture) =>
            {
                if (controller.SelectedIndex < controller.ViewControllers.Count() - 1)
                {
                    controller.SelectedIndex++;
                }
            });
            swipeLeft.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left;
            controller.View.AddGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft);
        }

        public void UpdateLayout(UITabBarController controller)
        {

        }
    }
}```
![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXNMJ.gif)
````

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12435

Comment: Hi, I have checked this code in my local site, it works. Whether you have a check with the latest version of xamarin forms and iOS?